# Rails has_many based on a json array column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-json

Is it possible to tell Rails to use a JSON column as the "backend" for a relation?
I have an `Article` model, that stores comment ids inside a JSON column `Article#comment_ids`:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  def comments
    Comment.where(id: comment_ids)
  end
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
end

Article.first.comment_ids
=> [1,2]

Article.first.comments
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f4d7cff7c08 id: 1>,#<Comment:0x00007f4d7cff7c08 id: 2>]
```

Is there any way to replace this code

```
def comments
  Comment.where(id: comment_ids)
end
```

with a

```
has_many :comments # somehow reference #comment_ids
```

Background: Other parts of my application use eager loading and stuff like `article.association(:comments).loaded?`. And because it's not a rails relation, this doesn't work for the comments relation.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions is this something that might help you?